# Reactor usage of Context contextWrite / deferContextual

Tags: java, project-reactor

i could not understand why this simple code is not working.
I m trying to save the initial value of my reactor Mono and reuse it later.

```java
        Mono.just("titi caca")
                .flatMap(m -> Mono.just(m).contextWrite(context -> context.put("INITIAL", m)))
                .log()
                .flatMap(m -> Mono.just(m.toUpperCase()))
                .log()
                .flatMap(m -> Mono.<String>deferContextual(contextView -> contextView.get("INITIAL")))
                .log()
                .subscribe();
```

it ends with "Context does not contain key: INITIAL" ? did i completly misunderstanding this feature ?

Comment: In short : context is propagated from **down**stream to **up**stream, through the subscription. It fits the case when you require information fetched by assembly or subscription code later in the chain. If you look at [the example in official doc](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#context), you will see that *contextWrite* is done at the end of the chain, and *deferContextual* is done before that. It may be counter-intuitive, but it is the purpose: you don't need such complex tool to propagate data from up to down (you just need to pass value as result of stream ops)

Comment: what i m trying to do is to avoid passing my initial object to my whole transformation chain to maximaze readability. is there something in the API that could help me to register my incoming message and get it later.